# why is it that my code is returning false?

Tags: java, string, comparison

```
public class practice {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = new String("abcdef");
    String str2 = new String("abcdef");
    System.out.println(str1==str2);
        }
}
```

can somebody explain why is it returning false even though they have the same string content .

Comment: You're attempting to compare the memory address of the two objects, not there contents.  You need to use `str1.equals(str2)` instead.  Have a look at [Comparing Strings and Portions of Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/comparestrings.html)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: You tagged this with "java string comparison." Did you try searching the site for those terms?